# How to add a button to a contextual ribbon in Revit

Tags: c#, ribbon, revit-api, revit

I am wanting to add buttons to certain contextual ribbons...  Specifically:

`Modify | Multi-Select`, `Modify | Pipes`, `Modify | Sprinklers`, `Modify | Pipe Accessories`, `Modify | Pipe Fittings`, `Modify | Mechanical Equipment` and 
`Modify | Generic Models`
 
and place the buttons within a panel of my creation.  How can I accomplish this?

### I've tried:

```
if (pTab.Id == "Modify | Pipes")
{
    foreach (var pPanel in pTab.Panels)
    {
        if (pPanel.Source.Id == "Edit") //Also tried edit_shr
        {// Add button.
            pIcon = Properties.Resources.AS_Revit_UI_hydraulicParameters_icon.GetHbitmap();
            var pBtn = new Autodesk.Windows.RibbonButton()
            {
                Name = "Hydraulic Parameters",
                Image = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(pIcon, IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(32, 32)),
                Id = "id_hydParam",
                AllowInStatusBar = true,
                AllowInToolBar = true,
                GroupLocation = Autodesk.Private.Windows.RibbonItemGroupLocation.Middle,
                MinHeight = 0,
                MinWidth = 0,
                Height = 32,
                Width = 32,
                IsEnabled = true,
                IsVisible = true,
                IsCheckable = true,
                ShowImage = true,
                ShowText = true,
                Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical,
                Text = "Hydraulic Parameters",
                Size = Autodesk.Windows.RibbonItemSize.Large,
                ResizeStyle = Autodesk.Windows.RibbonItemResizeStyles.HideText
            };

            pPanel.Source.Items.Add(pBtn);
            //Add event handler for button push
        }
    }
}
```

That, unfortunately, didn't work.  I'm sure this is possible - I just don't know how.  I feel like it's a matter of not know the Revit-issued tab names - like `Modify | Pipes` is really something like `modify_pipes` or something like that. 
 
 
The code above was me trying to put my button in a Revit panel...  Is there a way to add my own panel with my own buttons?  Something like this:

[image]

That's the ideal situation.  I'm more than comfortable with any other solutions like adding the buttons to existing panels.  Any help is good help!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can indeed be achieved in the following way:

- Create a ribbon panel button in the normal way, anywhere you like, in one of the default locations.
- Move the button to some other location using the .NET Automation API.

If your target location is a contextual tab, you may have to relocate your button every time the tab is opened.

This process is documented by The Building Coder:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/07/moving-an-external-command-button-within-the-ribbon.html

This is not recommended for production use, and I have heard reports that this approach may lead to crashes and file corruption, so beware!

Please note the [Disclaimer](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#4)!

Comment: Well if that's the case, then we're not doing it...  Thanks Jeremy!!  You're a huge help as usual.

Comment: Do you know of a way to add a custom panel to the `Modify` tab?  We already add buttons to it, but a whole panel would be nice and classy...

Comment: i think the same thing applies: create your panel as normal using the Revit API, and then move it to the desired location using .NET Automation.

Comment: @JeremyTammik So, can we not hide buttons on different modify tabs?

Comment: The Revit API enables you to enable and disable buttons using the command availability class. I do not believe it support hiding them. You may be able to implement that using the .NET Automation library functionality.

Comment: Here is a way to [add a custom button to the Modify tab](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/06/room-editor-live-and-unofficial-custom-ribbon-button.html#4). However, test it carefully and deploy with great care, since there it has been rumoured that this approach may cause instability and crash Revit!

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, and this is how:

- Create a custom RibbonPanel with my own buttons
- Copy the RibbonPanel to the Modify Tab (and remove the original (or not))
- subscribe to the propertychanged event of the modify tab
- if it is the title of the modify tab that changed AND it changed into "Modify | Pipes" (or whatever) enable my custom panel and make it visible.  If it is something else, disable it, and make it invisible.

Let me know if you need more detail